# How to use a module when it could not find a declaration file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

I have a typescript project using node.js. There is a module i want to use npm package country-code-lookup.

The problem is it does not have a supporting types declaration for it. However, i'd still like to use it.

Is it possible i could still use this package without the typings.

```
import * as CountryCodeLookup from "country-code-lookup";

   const countryCodes = CountryCodeLookup.countries;
   console.log(countryCodes);
```

I get the following error when typescript attempts to compile.

> TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module
>   'country-code-lookup'.
>   '/Users/kay/portal/node_modules/country-code-lookup/index.js'
>   implicitly has an 'any' type.
>         Try `npm install @types/country-code-lookup` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module
>   'country-code-lookup';`

Comment: The error tells you: "or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'country-code-lookup';`". So just add a declaration file in your project with that in it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you have no problems simply ignoring all type-checking features for this library, you have two options:

1. Add `// @ts-ignore` above all imports, like so:

```
// @ts-ignore
import * as CountryCodeLookup from "country-code-lookup";
```

2. Create a declaration file with `any` type, so all imports are automatically considered to be of `any` type.

To do so, create a file `src/types/country-code-lookup/index.d.ts`
Add the following declaration:

```
// country-code-lookup/index.d.ts
declare module 'country-code-lookup';
```

In this file, later you can add your own type definitions. If they are good enough, push them do [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped), so all the community can use and improve it!

Comment: How can it be pushed to DefinelyTyped?

Comment: It's a little complicated. Follow the steps in the official repo: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#how-can-i-contribute